# Win 7 wifi hotspot connection not able to share internet

Tags: stock-android, networking, windows, wifi-hotspot, ad-hoc-networks

I have created an ad-hoc wifi hotspot connection using

```
> netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=WinWlHS  key=MyPassword keyusage=persistent
```

Then I have started hotspot using

```
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

I have also shared the intenet connection with Microsoft virtual WIFI mini port & it's also showing that it can access Internet.

[image]

When I connect to this hotspot network on my android device it gets connected but there is no internet(All proxy settings have been taken care of). Anybody with some experience to this who can guide ?

**Note:** I am behind proxy, using windows 7 64 bit, Sophose 5.60 installed, Using static Ip.